# Copy and pasting button with content in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, append

I am trying to write a script in a web page that will sort of copy and paste a button and it's hidden content and then append in on the bottom of the first button. The problem is I am not very literate in JS.

So when one would press the "Add" button, button "Test Button #1" will be copied and appended to the bottom as "Test Button #2". Keep in mind that the button may contain a dropdown of sort in the actual script, this one was just shortened, so the second button would have to contain the same info as the first. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Please use my attempt at the bottom script as a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      min-width: 250px;
    }

    .testBtn {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
      color: white;
      border: none;
    }

    /* Style the header */
    .header {
      background-color: black;
      padding: 30px 40px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Clear floats after the header */
    .header:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
      border: none;
    }


    /* Style the "Add" button */
    .addBtn {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 25%;
      background: #d9d9d9;
      color: #555;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .addBtn:hover {
      background-color: #bbb;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="myDIV" class="header">
      <h2 style="margin:5px">Test Button List</h2>
      <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
    </div>

    <div class="myUL" id="myUL">
      <button class="testBtn">Test Button #1</button>
    </div>

    <script>
    function newElement() {
      var li = document.createElement("button");
      var inputValue = document.getElementById("myUL").value;
      var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
      li.appendChild(t);
      if (inputValue === !"") {
        document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
      }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

#################EDITED

I tried the node.clone() method, but still cannot append the button. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.testBtn {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  border: none;
}


/* Style the "Add" button */
.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
.Btn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.Btn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2 style="margin:5px">Test Button List</h2>
  <span onclick="newSample()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<div class="testBtn" id="testBtn">
  <button class="Btn">Test Button #1</button>
</div>

<script>
      function newSample() {
        var p = document.getElementById("testBtn");
        var p_prime = p.cloneNode(true);
        node.appendChild(p_prime);
      }       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's a few problems.

- ```
  var li = document.createElement("button");
  ```

  If it's a `<button>` why are you calling it `var li`? Use a meaningful name here.
- ```
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myUL").value;
  ```

  `#myUL` is a `<div>` (so why it's called `UL` is another mystery). You are treating it like an `<input />` by trying to get its value. If you want the HTML content, use `innerHTML`...
- ```
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  ```

  ... but you're creating a text node, so I don't know what you're expecting any more. It's all very confusing.
- ```
  li.appendChild(t);
  ```

  This is probably fine. You're appending a text node to a button. Seems ok.
- ```
  if (inputValue === !"") {
  ```

  Translation: "if `inputValue` is identical to `true`" - this can never happen because `inputValue` is a string and `true` is a boolean. Did you mean `inputValue !== ""`?

On the whole, it's a mess. What you probably want to do is get your "template" button and use `.cloneNode(true)` on it, then append that to the container.

Comment: This is very helpful, like I said I am not at all good with JS. I was just trying to do this with script from different sources.

Comment: You haven't defined `node` in your code. You probably want `p.parentNode.appendChild(p_prime);`